# Why do some MOSFETs have a resistor in series with the gate, and others have a resistor from gate to ground?

Tags: mosfet, digital-logic

I have seen many people connecting the mosfet in two configurations the first is when the resistor is in series with the gate and the second is when the resistor is in parallel with the gate which circuit is best when the input into the gate is a logic 1 (5V) or logic 0 (0V)?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Be sure to give a descriptive title to your questions.

Comment: How much current can your logic output deliver to the input capacitance of the MOSFET?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The resistors are used for different purposes. It's often good to have both.

The parallel resistor is to ensure that the MOSFET turns "off" if the input becomes open circuit or floats. This could be because of a connector or a microcontroller GPIO being tristated (eg. during brown-out reset).

The series resistor slows the switching of the MOSFET (which reduces the drive current and EMI at the expense of a bit of switching loss on each transistion) and can provide a certain amount of protection for the driving circuit if the MOSFET becomes shorted gate-to-drain. If you are switching a large MOSFET with a high frequency PWM you need to have a much lower value series resistor from the driver, if any, compared to simply switching a relay or on/off control of a motor.

For example, you could use a 1K series resistor and 100K from gate-to-source. That would only reduce the drive voltage by 1%.

Comment: Would the series resistor come before or after the parallel resistor

Comment: Yes. ;-) The best place to put the parallel resistor is right at the MOSFET but it reduces the gate voltage drive, so it's a trade-off.

Comment: I think then since I'm using the mosfet to switch just one led on and off but not using a high frequency. I'm connecting an 8 bit shift register to 8 led via 8 mosfets were the gate is connected to the outputs of the shift register. I just need a parallel resistor to limit the float voltages that the shift register might produce.

Comment: If the worst case power dissipation isn't enough to damage the MOSFET (say it turns half-on) and you don't care about the peak current from the driver maybe glitching the power supply or whatever, then you don't need either resistor. But determining that is another question, I think.

Answer (score 2):

The resistors serve two different purposes. The parallel resistor makes sure that the gate voltage goes to ground if the logic input is disconnected (or weak). The series resistor limits the gate current during switching.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the other answers, and for completeness, note that it's not uncommon for both resistors to be used, and that the "parallel" resistor as you call it may also be connected to a higher voltage than ground, if the circuit needs it.

[image: MOSFET with current limiting resistor and pull-down on gate]   [image: MOSFET with current limiting resistor and pull-up on gate]

It's important to observe that when both resistors are used, the value of the pull-down (or pull-up) resistor will more strongly effect the voltage level at the gate. This is because the two resistors form a resistor divider. Thus the pull-down resistor may need to have a large value. This keeps the ratio of voltage across the pull-down resistor to the "series" resistor larger.

Example: if the driver output is 5 V, and both resistors are 10K, the voltage at the gate is `5*(10k/(10k+10k))` = 2.5 V, which may or may not be enough.
If the pull-down resistor is 100k, the voltage at the gate is `5*(10k/(10k+100k))` = 4.55 V, which is much closer to the original driver level.

Here is a [**link to a web-based simulation**](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$%201%200.000005%2010.20027730826997%2050%205%2043%0A172%2064%2096%2064%2064%200%206%205%205%200%200%200.5%20Voltage%0Af%2016%20208%2064%20208%200%201.5%200.02%0Ag%2064%20224%2064%20272%200%0Ad%2064%20144%2064%20192%201%200.805904783%0Ar%2064%20144%2064%2096%200%20220%0Ar%200%20208%20-64%20208%200%2010000%0Ar%200%20256%200%20208%200%20100000%0A368%2016%20208%2016%20160%200%200%0Ag%200%20256%200%20272%200%0A172%20-64%20208%20-96%20208%200%206%205%205%200%200%200.5%20Voltage%0Aw%2016%20208%200%20208%200%0A). You can change the resistor values by double clicking on them. The "TP" (test point) value shows you the voltage on the gate of the MOSFET. Play around with it to get a better idea of what's going on.